# Laravel 4 Mcrypt at CLI

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-interface, mcrypt

I am trying to use `phpunit` with Laravel 4, but I have Mcrypt problem.

At `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php` line 29, Laravel checks to see if `mcrypt` is enabled.

```
if ( ! extension_loaded('mcrypt'))
{
    die('Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension.'.PHP_EOL);

    exit(1);
}
```

When I `phpunit` at CLI, it says;

```
Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension.
```

This is not possible because following commands show that everything is OK.

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.4.4 (cli)

$ php --ini
Loaded Configuration File: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/conf/php.ini

$ php -i | grep "mcrypt support"
mcrypt support => enabled
```

But... When I add following code at `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php` to see which PHP version is used, CLI displays `5.3.15`

```
die(phpversion().PHP_EOL);
```

I don't know how this could be possible.

After adding the above code; `php artisan` displays 5.4.4 but `phpunit` displays 5.3.15. This is nearly impossible because both use `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php` to check if Mcrypt is enabled.

I'm not sure but does Laravel change something when it's in `testing` environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue on my mac with two versions of php (that one coming out of the box and another one from macport).
so when using the command line, the php version you call depend of your bin path order (echo $PATH).

If you look at the hashbangs :

- artisan starts by #!/usr/bin/env php
- phpunit starts by #!/usr/bin/php

  ```
  $/usr/bin/env php -v
  PHP 5.3.25 (cli) (built: Jun  5 2013 12:14:23)

  $/usr/bin/php -v
  PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 28 2012 18:19:13)
  ```

Hope it helps,

Comment: I thought the same but both `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.php` and `vendor/bin/phpunit` starts with `#!/usr/bin/env php`, just like artisan. I installed PHPUnit via Composer, does this make a difference?

Comment: It worked. I had installed PHPUnit via Pear some time ago and terminal was still using that PHPUnit. I updated my `~/.bash_profile` and it works now. Thank you so much.

Comment: vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.php and vendor/bin/phpunit are probably not in your path, but /usr/bin/phpunit is. ;)